# React Hooks - custom useAuth hook does not work as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, createcontext

I am new to react and am experimenting a bit. I have a bit of code and I am not sure why it is not working. I tried to implement an own hook & context to provide user authentication data along my application.

The main parts pf the coding are as follows:

AuthContext.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AuthService } from './AuthService';


const initialContextState = {
    username: 'guest',
    token: null,
}

export const AuthContext = React.createContext(initialContextState);

export const useAuth = () => {
    const auth = React.useContext(AuthContext);
    return auth;
};

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState(initialContextState);
    
    const loginAsync = async (username, password)=>{
        await AuthService.authenticate(username, password); // some fetch call
        let token = AuthService.getToken();
        let usernameR = AuthService.getUsername();
        setAuth({
            username: usernameR,
            token: token
        });
    }

    const logoutAsync = async (username, password)=>{
        setAuth(initialContextState);
    }

    const isLoggedIn = () => {
        return auth.token !== null;
    }
    

    const value = {
        auth,
        loginAsync,
        logoutAsync,
        isLoggedIn,
    }
    
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
        {children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Now I have a LoginForm component where I use my awsome hook:

```
const LoginForm = ({ redirectedFrom  }) => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const {loginAsync, isLoggedIn} = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const login = async (e) => {
      await loginAsync(userName, password)
      let authenticated = isLoggedIn();

      if(authenticated){
        alert('You are logged in.');
        let redirectTo = (redirectedFrom) ? redirectedFrom: '/';
        navigate(redirectTo);
      }else{
        alert('Nope, wrong');
      }
  };

  return (
         //Username input + password input + login button

  );
};
```

ow the awsome hook does not seem to work as expected.

If login is clicked for the first time isLoggedIn returns false because my auth state in the auth provider is initial!

At the second click a true is returned. However the token value is from the last fetch call. So maybe something is wrong around "setAuth".

First I thought that it is some sort of async issue. Howeever according to console.log() expereiments it is not.

Could some awsome react pro tell me where my problem is?

I have the feeling that my hook implementation is not correct :(

Thx in advance :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that anyone who might want to help answer your question has the ability to understand what exactly isn't working and can debug why that's the case.